# Open Session In View (OSIV) and Hibernate Session flush

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, transactions

Following is a hypothetical situation on Spring 3.x and Hibernate3.x

I have a service layer in spring which invokes 3 DAOs to construct a model.
The DAOs are transactional(@Transactional) and have lazy loaded hibernate collections.
The service method causes a few updates ,along with the fetch of data.

A typical DAO method will be as follows -

```
public O create(I entity) throws GenericException {
    getOrCreateSession().save(entity);
    return (O)entity;
}
```

I have the following questions around OSIV -
1.How many times is this session flushed(database update) in the default AUTO mode?
2.Can OSIV be made to extend the session beyond a single request (to a conversation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The [AUTO flush mode](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-flush-strategies/) will execute the pending DML statements when:

- the current transaction is committed
- when a query might target an entity table, that's current enqueued for flushing

2. Spring Webflow has [support for long conversations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/webflow/persistence/HibernateFlowExecutionListener.html).